# Zend Controller configuration to use new Search form

Tags: php, zend-framework, model-view-controller

I purchased a boilerplate script for my own personal Google Drive or Dropbox, if you will. One of the first features I wanted to add to this script was the ability to search for files in the repository, by name( excluding certain regex for now). The script is coded in PHP, and I'm not familiar with the ZEND framework so resource locations have been a hassle. I've been reading the ZEND framework reference but I think I'm missing some essential knowledge:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/reference.html

**The error:**
    http://cl.ly/image/3A0B360T1B2f

**In a file called index.phtml in my /views directory:**

```
<?php
echo <<<DPRS
<html> <head>
<title>Search Form</title> <head>
<body>
<form id="myform" action="search.php" method="POST">
Search for: <input type="text" name="search_text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
DPRS;
?>
```

**In a file called search.php in my /controllers directory (I've omitted my db details, the db, table and column exist on my server):**

```
<?php
$search_val = $_POST['search_text'];

$hostname = "hostname"; 
$username = "username"; 
$password = "password"; 
$database = "database"; 
$tablename = "table"; 

$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if($connection) { 
if(mysql_select_db($database, $connection)) {
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tablename");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
if($row['COLUMN'] == $search_val) { 
echo $row['COLUMN'] . "
\n"; 
}
}
} else {
die("Could not connect to database " . $database);
}
} else {
die("Could not connect to host: " . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Help, pointers, manuals are all greatly appreciated!

Comment: If a new project you should use Zend Framework 2, just a thought ;) http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/user-guide/skeleton-application.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default Zend Framework directory structure must look like:

- application

  - controllers

    - SearchController.php
  - views

    - scripts

      - search

        - index.phtml

So instead of `search.php` you should name the controller `SearchController.php`.
The `index.phtml` view script get called if you call the `index` action from the controller. (http://www.yourdomain.com/search/index or only http://www.yourdomain.com/search)

The search controller should look like:

```
class SearchController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

    }
}
```

If you work with Zend Framework you can take [Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.form.html) for forms. [Quickstart Zend_Form](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.create-form.html)

Also please don't use `mysql_*` functions. With ZF there is [Zend_Db](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.db.html). ZF is not easy (especially ZF2). But it will pay off if you take some time to learn it. I recommend to go through the whole [Quickstart](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the guidance. I'm going to go through the quickstart so I'm better versed in the framework! Thanks for taking your time to help me.

Comment: you're welcome..I've learned a lot about PHP programming while working with ZF. It's a very clean code and they have nice concepts behind it. Don't be afraid to look at their sourcecode if something is unclear.